# jQuery find first element of class with unique id

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements which is something like this:

```
<article id="post-647" class="brand-search-result brand-alaffia hidden"></article>
<article id="post-647" class="brand-search-result brand-alaffia hidden"></article>
<article id="post-647" class="brand-search-result brand-alaffia hidden"></article>

<article id="post-650" class="brand-search-result brand-alter-eco hidden"></article>
<article id="post-650" class="brand-search-result brand-alter-eco hidden"></article>
<article id="post-650" class="brand-search-result brand-alter-eco hidden"></article>
```

Now what I want to is find the first of each unique id and remove the hidden class. This is what I have in jquery so far:

```
(function(){
    $("[id^=post-]").each(function(){
        $(this).first(".brand-search-result").removeClass('hidden');
    });
})();
```

Only problem is this running on every article element which makes sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: **ids need to be unique**

Comment: if you want to select more elements by unique string use classes

Comment: @theblindprophet quite right - except, it should be more than a suggestion.

Comment: You are correct sir, more of a mandate

Comment: You could use the name attribute instead of id if you really need to have a group subset of HTML elements with the same "thing" that identifies them as a group. Then you can use ("[name^=post-]").each ... instead to get all of them. You will need to iterate through all of them and store the first one in a variable, then check when the name changes the first time and that will tell you that this is the first element and remove the hidden class from it.

Comment: `Unique`. You keep saying that word.  I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store somewhere the information of the unique post. Skip future ones.

```
var processedPosts = {};

(function(){
$("[id^=post-]").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).prop("id") //modify to use unique ids (as suggested in comments)

    if (!processedPosts[id]) {
        $(this).first(".brand-search-result").removeClass('hidden');
        processedPosts[id] = true;
    }
});
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

You came close.

> '#' + $(this).attr('id')

'#' plus the id and then we use it as selector.

```js
$("[id^=post-]").each(function() {
  $( '#' + $(this).attr('id') ).first('.brand-search-result').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-647" class="brand-search-result brand-alaffia hidden">post-647</article>
<article id="post-647" class="brand-search-result brand-alaffia hidden">post-647</article>
<article id="post-647" class="brand-search-result brand-alaffia hidden">post-647</article>

<article id="post-650" class="brand-search-result brand-alter-eco hidden">post-650</article>
<article id="post-650" class="brand-search-result brand-alter-eco hidden">post-650</article>
<article id="post-650" class="brand-search-result brand-alter-eco hidden">post-650</article>
```

You don't need to store in array and check against it.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2Lhp5f1/)